# How can I add Google Tag Manager id to Meteor app?

Tags: meteor, google-tag-manager

I'm using okgrow analytics package to inject a Google Analytics tag into my Meteor app. But that package doesn't offer support for Google Tag Manager.

Does anyone know how to inject a GTM script into a Meteor project?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple and efficient way to insert a script you need on every page is to do it in the /client/main.html or /client/head.html file depending on which project structure you are following.